# Is there a way to query a collection that was previously populated from a jquery expression?

Tags: jquery

Rather than executing the same jquery expression several times, I'm populating a variable during `$(document).ready`:

```
var checkboxes = $('#<%=tbl.ClientID %> input[id*="chk"]');
```

Here, I am storing the list of checkboxes that end with "chk" within the table with the id of "`tbl`" in the variable checkboxes.

Later, I want to disable a button if none of the checkboxes are checked.

I'm attempting to do something like:

```
btn.disabled = $(checkboxes:checked').length == 0;
```

but nothing is happening.  Ideas?

Comment: P.S probably a typo but You're missing a `'`

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I actually modified my actual code to make it more readable for you guys :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkbox` in your code is a jQuery object.  You are trying to use it like a string.

You can take that list of checkboxes that are already in the jQuery object and then filter it down to a result that is just the ones that are currently checked and then check the length of that like this:

```
btn.disabled = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length === 0;
```

Or, you could run an entirely new selector from scratch where you combine `":checked"` with your previous selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a jQuery collection, you can filter it down. You can use the [`$.fn.filter` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to conditionally exclude/include items in the new collection, or use something like [`$.fn.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to pass in a new selection to match all children against.

Read further online at http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/.